# how to get the event not the state when a button is highlighted

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a button for which I need to change the image of the button whenever it is highlighted. I have written the following code `button.setImage("highlited_image", for: .highlighted)`. The code works if I specifically set the state of the button to highlighted. How can I get the event when the state of the button is changing?

Answer (score 6):

The property `isHighlighted` is KVO compliant, you could add an observer

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

var observation : NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    observation = button.observe(\.isHighlighted, options: [.old, .new], changeHandler: { _, change in
        if change.oldValue! != change.newValue! { print(change.newValue!) }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From Docs:

> A control becomes highlighted when a touch event enters the control’s bounds, and it loses that highlight when there is a touch-up event or when the touch event exits the control’s bounds...

Simplified: `UIButton` becomes highlighted when user presses button until user unpresses it.

So if you need to handle moment when button is pressed, set action for button for event `.touchUpInside`

---

But if you’re interested just in images for certain states. Set image for state `.normal` as well as for state `.highlighted`

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setImage("highlited_image", for: .highlighted)
```

should be

```
button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "highlited_image"), for: .highlighted)
```

I guess...